# ptファイルからonnxファイルに変換できません！

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch

こんにちは。Yolov5で作成した.ptファイルをOpenCVで使うために.onnxファイルに変換したいです。

```
import torch

# モデルを読み込む
model = torch.load('best.pt')
model.eval()  # 推論モードに設定

import torch.onnx as onnx

# 入力テンソルの例を作成（必要に応じて適切な形状とデータ型を指定してください）
example_input = torch.randn(1, 3, 224, 224)

# ONNX形式に変換
onnx_model_path = 'best.onnx'
torch.onnx.export(model, example_input, onnx_model_path, verbose=True)
```

以前はこのコードでできたはずなのですが、

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models.yolo'
```

と出ます。バージョンが変わったからかなと思って試したのですが、うまくいきません。
同じようなエラーで困っている方、解決方法をご存じの方は、教えていただければ幸いです。よろしくお願いします。